# How to make my program increase the price of the book (percent) depending on user inputs?

Tags: c, file-processing

I've made a program that reads a file named "books.txt" and displays its contents. In the file, there is a price for each of the 4 books.

I'm not sure how to make my program increase the price of the book (percent) depending on user inputs; for example, the user is prompted to enter a number and that number (which is a percentage) is multiplied by the price of each book and gives the updated price.

How do I do it?

Here's my code:

```c
int main() {
    /* File pointer to hold reference to our file */
    FILE * fPtr;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int totalRead = 0;
    /* 
     */
    fPtr = fopen("books.txt", "r");
    
    if (fPtr == NULL) {
      printf("Unable to open file.\n");
      printf("Please check whether file exists and you have read privilege.\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("File opened successfully. Reading file contents line by line. \n\n");
   
    while (fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, fPtr) != NULL) {
      totalRead = strlen(buffer);
      /*
       */
      buffer[totalRead - 1] = buffer[totalRead - 1] == '\n' 
                              ? '\0' 
                              : buffer[totalRead - 1];
      printf("%s\n", buffer);
    } 
    
    fclose(fPtr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a very unclear question. Can you at least provide some sample input and expected output?

Comment: example: https://gyazo.com/2422876736f5351dd54f207feaf3bdd2

Comment: Please do not provide links to other sites. StackOverflow has all of the resources necessary for asking questions. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file and store all the book data in some array of struct such as

```
typedef struct {
    int id;
    char *title;
    char *author;
    int year;
    float price;
}Book;
```

Then ask for the percentage to the user and re-write the file calculating the new `price` for each `Book` (`price += percentage/100`)

To re-write the file you need to open the file with `"w` permits. You can check for documentation [here](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.fwrite.php). Don't forget to close `fPtr` before opening the same file again with write permits